# Understanding C++ Parameters in random number generator call

Tags: c++, multithreading, hash, parameters

I'm going through some examples in a book entitled Mastering C++ Multithreading and I've come across some code that I don't fully understand.

In this function a random number generator wrapper function I don't understand the parameters.

```
int randGen(const int& min, const int& max){

    static thread_local mt19937 generator(hash<thread::id>() (this_thread::get_id()));

    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);

    return distribution(generator);
}
```

The code I don't understand is the parameters in the generator function call

```
hash<thread::id>() (this_thread::get_id())
```

Is `hash<thread::id>()` a function taking in the return value from `this_thread::get_id()`?

Any help would be much appreciated, or if I need to supply more info. plz just shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hash<thread::id>()` you *create an object* of the [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) class template.

Then you call that objects [`operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator()) function, passing `this_thread::get_id()` as argument.

---

If we split it up, it might be easier to understand:

```
hash<thread::id> my_hash;  // Create object
my_hash(this_thread::get_id());  // Use the function call operator
```

The last, using the function call operator, it equal to

```
my_hash.operator()(this_thread::get_id());  // Use the function call operator
```

The result of the function call operator is then used as argument to the constructor of the `generator` object.

Comment: which in turn hashes the value returned by the (this_thread::get_id()) call?

Comment: Brilliant , absolute class, thank you so much, accepting answer now , thanks again.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this hash<thread::id>() is an example of a functor?

Comment: @DTurner `hash<thread::id>()` creates an object which have an `operator()` member function, which means it can be used as a function, which is the typical use of a "functor" object.

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated